# How would I layer an element below another?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/pzRV8/

At the bottom of that snippet of code, there's a section named `container`. Now, I'm trying to overlay the drop shadow over it, instead of under it. Thanks.

Comment: this is a mess.  which shadow... is the missing picture something important?  I recommend you take out all code that isn't absolutely necessary for this example... and clarify what you want.  most likely you could use z-index as suggested below... but you could also most likely just order your html in the correct order...

Answer (score 2):

DOM elements layer based on positioning and z-index. The higher the z-index, the higher the element is (picture a deck of cards where 0 is the bottom card, 51 being the top card - the numbers can also be negative). For z-index to work properly, the element must have a position of absolute.

Position Absolute

```
position: absolute;
```

Z-Index

```
z-index: 0;
```

To make the changes (although they are static and I am not a fan of static content) try this:

Add this to your container definition:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
```

Change your `header definition`'s margin bottom to this:

```
margin-bottom: 352px;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wh8tX/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result through `z-index` property but remember `z-index`only work with positing so i have defined the positioning in `.spotlight` & `.container`  class.

check it the demo

i hope you are looking like this :- http://jsfiddle.net/pzRV8/6/

Comment: Your demo looks exactly as the original.

Comment: To position a container relative/absolute to another, you should define the parent container as relative/absolute. if you have a look at Travis's answer, you will what the OP wanted in he's question.

Comment: @Dementic ya i forgot to gave positioning to parent div but now i have defined in parent div the answer is same as earlier because OP has made separate div's.... and one thing where that content has gone in the container class see my answer and compare with Travis's answer if you will remove his z-index u will get that content but you can see that content in container class in my answer...........

Answer (score 0):

You need `zindex` for that. remember `zindex` will only work with `position`. Position can be relative, fixed, absolute

```
<div style="zindex:1; position:relative">first</div>
<div style="zindex:2; position:relative">second</div>
```

Comment: remember positioning will work only if parent container is given position also. :P

Comment: you missed a dash, bro

Answer (score 0):

since the stacking is ordered by the `html` document tag (unless changed)
then `header` automaticly will get `z-index:1`
and `.container` will get `z-index:2`

you need to override it as follows:

give `header` `position:relative` and `z-index:1`

give `.container` `z-index:-1`

see working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pzRV8/9/